# Is not it inefficient to store blockchain blocks in an array? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain

I've read some articles on creating blockchain using Node.js and one common thing I found that they are using arrays to store blocks.

I don't think it is efficient to use an array here because the size of the chain may increase to hundreds of MB.

So my questions are what is the best way to store blocks? Array? Redis? Something else?

Edit:

One of the articles I have read:
https://codingislove.com/simple-blockchain-javascript/

See the array "chain" in the Blockchain class.

Comment: Please, show a source with some context. Because, as it stands, it's possible that the array is just transient storage to then put it somewhere more sensible.

Comment: I've added a link to one of the articles/tutorials. Let me know if it helps,

Comment: I think this is just an unoptimized example to show how a blockchain works. Of course storing the entire blockchain in an array is going to backfire as soon as the array becomes big enough or the process long-lived enough. Just take it as an educational example, not as how you would do that in production.

Comment: TypedArrays might be better. Or some external specialized storage (Redis whatever)

Comment: @federico-klez-culloca is correct, This implementation would not be better for production, Not just the array and memory usage

Answer (score 0):

The higher length of your block chain, the better that your block chain will get, As of my knowledge to verify a single block, the bit coin block chain (the implementation) does not goes till the root block, bitcoin block chain uses an algorithm depend on the amount of the transaction, how many blocks they need to travel to (higher the amount, higher the reverse traversing).

So my suggestion is to keep a constant amount of blocks on the memory to verify, And persist other blocks to a database or key value storage(like redis) and load them when required.